# iOS subview custom transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

When presenting a UIViewController that implements `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` it is easily possible to customize the `viewtransition`.

Now I would like to know if I can customize a `viewtransition` for a subview? Lets say I have a tapable tile that currently flips when tapped (UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight). Although that is a very nice effect I rather would like to customize this transition. But I do not know how to start..

To clarify I would like to use an `AnimationController<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>` to handle my subviewtransition - is that possible?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of help exactly do you need? You react to users touch by running a standard animation (I assume you are using `
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`) - instead you would need to write your own animation code. Here are two first results for "UIView animation" : http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

Comment: To clarify I would like to use an `AnimationController<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>` to handle my subviewtransition - is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not possible out of the box but **there are some ways** to achieve that but this will need some deeper knowledge of how the custom transition are working in detail.

Here are two articles describing what you are looking for in detail:

Custom Container View Controller Transitions
http://www.objc.io/issue-12/custom-container-view-controller-transitions.html

Interactive Custom Container View Controller Transitions
http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/5/12/interactive-custom-container-view-controller-transitions

Answer (score 1):

Answering with regards to your comment : you cannot.

From `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol documentation :

> Adopt the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol in objects that implement the animations for a custom **view controller** transition. The methods in this protocol let you define an animator object, which creates the animations for transitioning a **view controller** on or off screen in a fixed amount of time.

This protocol is only for `UIViewControllers` (and its descendants), and `UIView` doesn't inherit from it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does that mean when I use a viewcontroller for a Subview I then can use an AnimationController to handle my viewtransition?